# How to set values in span elements based on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

What I am trying to do is, I have different automated buttons with data attributes, and when any one button is clicked the data from that button should be shown in different span elements.

Here is my code:

**For the automated buttons**.

```
 <button 
      class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
      name="add_this_<?php echo $i; ?>" 
      id="add_this_<?php echo $i; ?>" 
      data-hname="<?php echo $hotel_name; ?>" 
      data-elem="<?php echo $i; ?>" 
      onclick="total_rate()">
Select
</button>
```

**For Span element:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10">
    Hotels: <span id="hotels"></span>
    </div>
```

**Js code:**

function total_rate(){

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var elem = button.data('elem');
    var hname = button.data('hname');

    var s_tax = $("#s_tax_"+elem).val();
    var cost_em = $("#em_"+elem).val();
    var cat_cost = $("#sel_cat_"+elem).val();

    var rooms = $("#rooms").val();
    var per = $('#persons').val();
    var mattress = per - (rooms*2);
    var cost_hotel = parseInt((cat_cost * rooms) + (cost_em * mattress));
    var cost_hotel_final = cost_hotel + (s_tax/100 * cost_hotel);

    $("#total_cost").html(cost_hotel_final);
    $("#hotels").html(hname);


 });
```

}

The problem is that I am not getting the valued in the span element.
Any type of help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the most informative heading i've ever seen :) pls make js fiddle

Comment: iam not able to show the values in span elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me changing `$(event.relatedTarget);` with `$(event.target);`:
[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cavatibesi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: thanx @vithozor for ur help. it worked for me also.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button 
      class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
      name="add_this_<?php echo $i; ?>" 
      id="add_this_<?php echo $i; ?>" 
      data-hname="<?php echo $hotel_name; ?>" 
      data-elem="<?php echo $i; ?>" 
      onclick="total_rate(this)">
Select
</button>

function total_rate(elem)
{
    var #elem = $(elem);
    var id = #elem.attr("id");
    var datahname = #elem.attr("data-hname");
    var dataelem = #elem.attr("data-elem");

    //.....stuff and things
    var $hotels = $('#hotels');
    $hotels.html(datahname)
}
```